# PDO bindParam not binding in ON... AND LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wamp

I am trying to convert some queries to PDO and am having difficulties with one query in particular running on a WAMP server. I am able to get the query to work fine if I "force" the paramater as a String if I structure the line as follows, but the downside is it's not bound and I have to have the query in the same PHP file:

```
AND B.LongName LIKE '" . $searchPattern . "'
```

The query that does not bind is set up as follows:

```
$query_NotWorking = "SELECT
A.Description AS 'Description',
A.LongName AS 'LongName',
A.thisID AS 'This_ID',
B.LongName AS 'TargetName',
B.TargetID AS 'Target_ID',
B.NodeNumber AS 'Node',
FROM Sources A
LEFT JOIN Targets B
    ON A.thisID = B.DestID
    AND B.LongName LIKE :SearchPattern
    WHERE B.LongName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 'LongName', 'TargetName';";
```

The PHP code in the page that calls the query is as follows:

```
$searchPattern = "%Pattern%";

$stmt_Copy1 = $dbh_Pri -> prepare($query_NotWorking);
$stmt_Copy2 = $dbh_Sec -> prepare($query_NotWorking);

$stmt_Copy1 -> bindParam(':SearchPattern', $searchPattern, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
$stmt_Copy1 -> execute();

$stmt_Copy2 -> bindParam(':SearchPattern', $searchPattern, PDO::PARAM_STR, 15); 
$stmt_Copy2 -> execute();
```

Comment: Is there anything in the error logs?

Comment: Conventionally ,this is done with a CONCAT on the mysql side to surround your input param in `%` wildcards.:  `"LongName LIKE CONCAT('%', :SearchPattern, '%')`. I would expect yours to work though when the variable already has `%`. In what way did it fail?

Comment: Note the `LongName IS NOT NULL` isn't really necessary because the `LIKE` condition already requires it not be null.

Comment: When I turn PDO debugging on it says Uncaught PDO exception 8018 Mycrosoft ODBC SQL Server Driver Invalid parameter 4 (''): Data Type 0x23 is deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter. .... use current large object types instead. Doesn't make sense because I'm trying to pass a string. I removed the %% in the variable and did the concat but same error.